# Can we execure the ORACLE procudure by skipping some mandatory parameters?

Tags: oracle

I want to execute the procedure as it is having no.of paramters, some of them are not optional.
can't i execure it by taking my priority parameters only.

Comment: If they don't have a default value you have to specify a value for them. That's the meaning of "mandatory"

Comment: The choice between mandatory and optional should always be clear. If you define "priority" as mandatory ones, then as a consequence the "non-priority" should be optional. If you write a procedure, you'll very quickly see why a parameter is mandatory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot skip mandatory parameters, but you can omit optional:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE myproc(p1 IN NUMBER, p2 IN NUMBER DEFAULT 1, p3 IN NUMBER) 
AS
BEGIN
  NULL;
END;

BEGIN
  myproc(p1=>1, p3=>2);  
END;
----
anonymous block completed


BEGIN
  myproc(p3=>2);  
END;
-----
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'MYPROC'
```